# How can I post my href value in an ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an action that allows me to post an anchor href with an ajax call. Firstly the anchor tag is created with a backend set up so it cannot be inside a form etc so that is not going to work.

Here is the markup for the button, the href is added dynamically with js:

```
<a class="js-add-to-cart button buying-options buy-button" data-products-in-cart="<?= $products_in_cart ?>">
                Select a size
            </a>
```

I have currently got this code working which posts the anchor:

```
jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('a.buy-button').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        async: true,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            jQuery('#result').hide();
                            jQuery('#ajax-loader').show();
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, thrown){
                            alert(xhr + ',' + status+ ',' + thrown);
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                            jQuery('#ajax-loader').hide();
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            jQuery('#result').empty().append(data);
                            jQuery('#result').fadeIn('slow');
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
```

It works but my only issue is that it basically does a get request and in the header network response I get this:

[image: Network response]

This does not post the add to cart url and make the product added to cart.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: _"post an anchor href with an ajax call"_ why? This seems horribly inefficient and smell like an XY-problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: is the URL retrieved from 'jQuery(this).attr('href')'  add?product=762&qty ?

Comment: Hi JohnnyFaldo, yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps using the [`.post()` shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) will help you (and also clean up your code).

I'm assuming that you are not using the $ alias for jQuery because you are not aware of it, and not because of any conflict issues.

```
$(function(){
  $('a.buy-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#result').hide();
    $('#ajax-loader').show();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
      $('#ajax-loader').hide();
      $('#result').empty().append(data);
      $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah its exactly like it did before. It posts the ajax but I am not seeing anything added.

Comment: Do you know if I can access more data that is in the url from the data variable so for instance data.cart or data.name etc so I can use the success function

Answer (score 1):

try to see if the POST-action is actually triggered within the PHP code. It seems like it should be working.

Also the 'async' parameter is superfluous since you're already calling an A-jax function